# css link automatic margin to bigger link

Tags: html, css

I've the following problem:

[image]

The a tags automatically align to the bottom of the bigger a tag.
I would like to know why and what i can do against it.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

#navigation {
  background-color: #760209;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
}

#navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  /*line-height: 55px;*/
}

#navigation .logo {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <div class="container_12">
    <a class="logo" href="#">test1</a>
    <a class="btn" href="#">Mein Profil</a>
    <a class="btn" href="#">Fragen</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because by default `baseline` property is `bottom`, this is the main reason they aligned from bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `vertical-align` css property.
You can either use `vertical-align: middle;` or `vertical-align: top;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

#navigation {
  background-color: #760209;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
}

#navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  vertical-align: middle; /*  <-------  */
}

#navigation .logo {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <div class="container_12">
    <a class="logo" href="#">test1</a>
    <a class="btn" href="#">Mein Profil</a>
    <a class="btn" href="#">Fragen</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a `vertical-align` to your `<a>`

```
#navigation a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    /*line-height: 55px;*/
    vertical-align:middle; //This line over here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
.btn{
   vertical-align:top; 
}
```

if you need to align them to the top.

The default value of vertical align is **baseline**, which means that the element will be aligned to the baseline of the parent element.

That's why in your case the other 2 links seems aligned to the bottom comparing to the first element, just because of different font-size.